# MediaStreamSource not working properly in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-audio, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a project that utilizes original **libFLAC.dll** code to play FLAC files on Windows Phone 8.0. It used to work both in MediaElement and in background on WP 8.0, but after updating the project to Windows Phone 8.1, the sound became flickering and the components began "stack overflow"-ing.

I have updated the project to Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime project since Silverlight 8.1 doesn't support Background Audio. Though the problems were when using both Background Audio and MediaElement in Windows Phone Runtime app.

As it seems unclear, I want to clarify: I have created a *MediaStreamSource adapter* that hooks Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSource events and does all the work. I don't use Silverlight's MediaStreamSource implementation of course.

I have created a [thread on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/37ac0ed7-1884-4251-9914-07fae6467b98/mediastreamsource-not-working-properly-in-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop) where one can find more details, and open-sourced [the project on CodePlex](https://wp8libflac.codeplex.com/) so everyone can just take the source code for both WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 and see what's gone wrong.

I really hope someone could find workaround or at least make Microsoft aknowledge the problem.

Comment: Please clarify in your question if you upgraded to Silverlight 8.1, or a Universal App.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT I have updated the question. I have used Windows Phone Runtime 8.1 project, not Silverlight 8.1 (since it doesn't support new background audio). You can take the code from CodePlex.

Comment: Okay, but then you cannot use MediaStreamSource, as it's not compatible with Universal Applications. You'll need to rewrite the code as appropriate to work under the Windows Runtime.

Comment: Of course you can use MediaStreamSource in Universal. Why do you think you cant???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to MSDN forums community an @mcosmin especially, the solution was found and it is pretty simple.

To fix this, I simply need to set the `Duration` property of the `MediaStreamSample`, because unlike Silverlight's sample, WinRT's sample cannot calculate it on its own.